# solution of a mixed difference and differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to solve the following difference and differential equation:

$a\frac{d f(x)}{d x} = \frac{d f(2x)}{d x}$,

where $a<1$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x)=1$.

Comment: This is not a PDE, it is a mixed difference and ordinary differential equation.

Comment: sorry, already changed it

Comment: If $a>0$, the general solution $f$ of the equation is any antiderivative of $p(\log x) x^{-\lambda}$, with $p(t)$ a $\log 2$-periodic function and $\lambda:=-\log a /\log 2$. You should then check whether there is  such an $f$ that is integrable on $L^1(0,+\infty)$, a fact that possibly depends on $a$. In this case you can normalize $f$   and satisfy the other condition too.

Comment: @PietroMajer: shouldn't $\lambda$ be $-\log(a/2)/\log 2$ instead? As I understand it, we have $\frac{df(2x)}{dx}(x)=2\frac{df(x)}{dx}(2x)$. Maybe the poster should clarify the intended meaning.

Comment: Maybe. The notation is maybe a bit ambiguous. I read $df(2x)/dx$ as the derivative of $f$ evaluated in $2x$, i.e $f'(2x)$ (btw that's also why I never use the $df/dx$ notation)

Comment: it is kind of confusing. What I mean on $\frac{df(2x)}{dx}$ is the derivative of $f(z)$ at $z=2x$.

Comment: Well, then, I guess the less ambiguous writing is $\frac{df}{dx}(2x)$.